# Removing similar Dates from a List inside a Dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary where the values of the dictionary are lists of dates. For each key, if, in the list of dates, there are dates within one month of each other, I only want to take the last listed date within the one month period.

For example, I have a dictionary as follows:

```
a : ['2020-12-11'] 
b : ['2020-05-30', '2022-09-11'] 
c : ['2021-07-28', '2022-07-20', '2022-07-07'] 
d : ['2022-04-17', '2022-04-18', '2022-04-15', '2022-08-20']
```

Now, since I only want to take the last listed date with the one month period for each value, I'm trying to get the following output:

```
a : ['2020-12-11'] 
b : ['2020-05-30', '2022-09-11'] 
c : ['2021-07-28', '2022-07-07'] 
d : ['2022-04-15', '2022-08-20']
```

The output value does not change for `a` or `b` since there are no dates within a one month range of each other. The output value for `c` changes since `2022-07-20` and `2022-07-07` are within one month of each other, and since `2022-07-07` is listed last it is kept in the list (despite `2022-07-20` being at a later date). For `d`, the same thing should happen - `2022-04-17`, `2022-04-18`, `2022-04-15` are all within 1 month of each other, but `2022-04-15` is listed last so we want that, while `2022-08-20` is more than a month away so it's kept in too.

If anyone knows how to help me with this problem I would greatly appreciate it, since I'm not sure how to approach this problem, especially in a computationally fast way. Thank you!

EDIT:

I used the codes below and while they worked for the most part I noticed that for some lists, despite the dates being within one month of each other, are still there even after running your code (for example, `['2022-03-01', '2022-02-16']`). This is likely because the codes below group strictly by the month value. Is there a way to generalize it to "within 30 days of each other" instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use groupby from itertools:

```
from itertools import groupby   

input_dict = {
        "a" : ['2020-12-11'],
        "b" : ['2020-05-30', '2022-09-11'],
        "c" : ['2021-07-28', '2022-07-20', '2022-07-07'],
        "d" : ['2022-04-17', '2022-04-18', '2022-04-15', '2022-08-20'],
    }

new_dict = {k: [list(g)[-1] for _, g in groupby(v, key=lambda x: x[:7])] for k, v in input_dict.items()}
```

New dict is equal to:

```
{'a': ['2020-12-11'],
 'b': ['2020-05-30', '2022-09-11'],
 'c': ['2021-07-28', '2022-07-07'],
 'd': ['2022-04-15', '2022-08-20']}
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay! I just tried your answer too and it also works! I guess my questions are the same as I had for the other answer: how does the line of code you wrote 'know' to only look for dates with a one month period? And, if I wanted to change it to say, 10 days instead of one month, would it be easy to do? Sorry they might be dumb questions but it's hard for me to understand what's happening in that line of code! Thanks!

Comment: The main idea is x[:7] - you only take part of the string '2020-07' for grouping. So no it can not be extended to 10 days instead of month, it would be a completely different code. Are you looking for a version where you can put 10 days? How do you start the 10 days period, you need to give more details then

Comment: And it's not even clear what is 10 days period when your dates are not sorted like in your example

Comment: I understand, thank you! Regarding my second question, it's not too important, I was mostly curious if the line of code could be generalized so please disregard it. I have accepted your answer (although the other code may be quicker, you helped explain it to me in a bit more detail so I appreciate it!)

Comment: Zaikarov - Sorry, I have a follow up question if that's okay. I noticed that some lists, despite being within one month of each other, are still there even after running your code (for example, `['2022-03-01', '2022-02-16']`). This is likely because it is grouped strictly by the month value, but is there maybe a way to change it to "within 30 days of each other" instead?

Comment: Within 30 days is not difficult to do. I suggest you post another question and will get a quick answer. I can also look at it if you post a link here

Comment: Thank you! I will create a new question a little later today or maybe tomorrow at the latest (I don't spam the forum too much)

Comment: Sorry for the trouble, as a follow up, if possible could you help me with this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74242088/removing-dates-within-n-days-of-each-other-in-dictionaries

Answer (score 1):

Put the dates in dicts where the key is the month (i.e. the first seven characters of the string), then pull the values back out of the dicts to make the new lists.

```
>>> dates = {
...     'a' : ['2020-12-11'],
...     'b' : ['2020-05-30', '2022-09-11'],
...     'c' : ['2021-07-28', '2022-07-20', '2022-07-07'],
...     'd' : ['2022-04-17', '2022-04-18', '2022-04-15', '2022-08-20'],
... }
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint({k: list({d[:7]: d for d in v}.values()) for k, v in dates.items()})
{'a': ['2020-12-11'],
 'b': ['2020-05-30', '2022-09-11'],
 'c': ['2021-07-28', '2022-07-07'],
 'd': ['2022-04-15', '2022-08-20']}
```

Conveniently, shoving a list of colliding items into a dict leaves you with the last item, which is exactly what you want; if you didn't want that, you could sort each list before putting it into the dict.

Comment: This is the fastest working answer, even though hard to comprehend. I could not get a faster code than that.