# Removing dates within 'n' days of each other in Dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas, date, dictionary, datetime

I have a dictionary where the values of the dictionary are lists of dates. For each key, if, in the list of dates, there are dates within 30 days (or more generally `n` days) of each other, I only want to take the last listed date.

For example, I have a dictionary as follows:

```
a : ['2020-12-11'] 
b : ['2020-05-30', '2022-09-11'] 
c : ['2021-07-28', '2022-07-20', '2022-07-07', '2022-06-30'] 
d : ['2022-04-17', '2022-04-18', '2022-04-15', '2022-08-20']
```

Now, since I only want to take the last listed date within the 30 day period for each value, I'm trying to get the following output:

```
a : ['2020-12-11'] 
b : ['2020-05-30', '2022-09-11'] 
c : ['2021-07-28', '2022-06-30'] 
d : ['2022-04-15', '2022-08-20']
```

The output value does not change for `a` or `b` since there are no dates within 30 days range of each other. The output value for `c` changes since `2022-07-20`, `2022-07-07`, and `2022-06-30` are within 30 days of each other, and since `2022-06-30` is listed last it is kept in the list (despite `2022-07-20` being at a later date). For `d`, the same thing should happen - `2022-04-17`, `2022-04-18`, `2022-04-15` are all within 30 days of each other, but `2022-04-15` is listed last so we want that, while `2022-08-20` is more than 30 days away so it's kept in too.

If anyone knows how to help me with this problem I would greatly appreciate it since I'm not sure how to approach it, especially in a computationally fast way. Moreover, how can this be generalized to make it 60 days, 100 days etc.? Thank you!

Comment: What do you want to do when you have a string of dates where each is within 30 days of the next, but it's more than 30 from the first to the last?  E.g. [2022-04-17, 2022-04-07, 2022-03-27, 2022-03-17, 2022-03-07, 2022-02-27]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just loop through the dict, then loop through inner list, transform values to datetime and compare them with last value in inner list

```
test_dict = {
    "a" : ['2020-12-11'],
    "b" : ['2020-05-30', '2022-09-11'] ,
    "c" : ['2021-07-28', '2022-07-20', '2022-07-07', '2022-06-30'] ,
    "d" : ['2022-04-17', '2022-04-18', '2022-04-15', '2022-08-20'],
}


from datetime import datetime, timedelta
def only_leave_last_date(d: dict, days_gap:int) -> dict:
    new_dict = {}
    for key, value in d.items():
        if not value:            
            new_value_str = []
        else:
            new_value_dt = [datetime.strptime(value[0], '%Y-%m-%d')]
            new_value_str = [value[0]]
            for date_str in value[1:]:
                date = datetime.strptime(date_str, '%Y-%m-%d')
                if abs(date - new_value_dt[-1]) <= timedelta(days=days_gap):
                    new_value_dt[-1] = date
                    new_value_str[-1] = date_str
                else:
                    new_value_dt.append(date)
                    new_value_str.append(date_str)
        new_dict[key] = new_value_str
    return new_dict

only_leave_last_date(test_dict, days_gap=30)
```

Output:

```
{'a': ['2020-12-11'],
 'b': ['2020-05-30', '2022-09-11'],
 'c': ['2021-07-28', '2022-06-30'],
 'd': ['2022-04-15', '2022-08-20']}
```

Comment: Thanks for that! This method similar to what I did (your code is a LOT neater and more concise than mine though!) I was mostly curious if there's an alternative way of doing it since I don't usually use dictionaries and I am ignorant of all their functions/capabilities. I really appreciate all the help, thanks again!